# Angular filter based on dynamic list of IDs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

In my Angular app, I want to filter the items generated on a dropdown button with `ng-repeat` based on a list of IDs that I already generate dynamically.

This list is basically an array of numbers that gets updated dynamically with `$scope.$watchCollection`, e.g.:

```
$scope.selectedBPs = [1, 2]
```

Each item I generate with `ng-repeat` on the aforementioned dropdwon button has an id property. What I want the filter to do, is to only show a specific item if `$scope.selectedBPs` contains its id.

Currently my HTML is:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li ng-repeat="marker in vm.markers" ng-click="progressMarkerSelected.name = marker.name;">
        <a href role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">{{marker.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So basically, I only want the marker to appear if `$scope.selectedBPs.indexOf(marker.bpId) > -1` (bpId being the item's id).

Is it possible to do this with a filter?

How do I pass `$scope.selectedBPs` to an angular filter, so that the dropdown list also gets updated dynamically whenever the list changes?

Comment: so you want to remove items from your array in case or a certain condition? if I understood correctly you can do it with a filter. so only the items which exist in the selectedBPs appear. passing items to filters like so {{marker in vm.markers | bpsFilter:selectedBPs}} then in the filter receive the field , if you need an example let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom filter in Angular, which can do anything you want, the syntax is simple, eg: ng-repeat="marker in vm.markers | filter : myAmazingFilter".

In this custom filter you will receive your iterable item as argument, so you can do your test to show or not.

See this example below:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope){
 
  $scope.cars = [
    {
      id: 1,
      'name': 'Mustang'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      'name': 'Corvette'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      'name': 'Camaro'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      'name': 'Ford GT'
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.selectedIDs = [1,3];
  
  $scope.myCustomFilter = function(item){
    
    if ($scope.selectedIDs.indexOf(item.id) >= 0){ //Return true if item.id is Mustang or Camaro
      
      return true; //Return true to show your item in repeat
      
    }
    
    return false;
    
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  
    <ul ng-repeat="car in cars | filter: myCustomFilter">
      <li>{{car.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh so a filter can simply be a function that I declare within my Controller? Thank you!